ML Kit PoseDetection cannot access Detector
I wanted to create an app via React-Native for pose detection by using ML Kit.
I used the instructions of the Google Ml Kit website and I used the following task:
poseDetector.process(image)
But when building, I get the error:
 error: cannot access Detector
      poseDetector.process(image)
                  ^
  class file for com.google.mlkit.vision.common.internal.Detector not found

I used several imports in the Java file, but apparently I get the same error over and over again but I don't know why.
I can't find anything to it. It seems nobody has the same problem. I thought maybe it's an easy fix.
Imported several dependencies in build.gradle and libraries in the application.
For the application (full code):
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Promise;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.common.InputImage;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.common.PointF3D;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.common.Triangle;


import com.google.mlkit.vision.pose.accurate.AccuratePoseDetectorOptions;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.interfaces.Detector;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.pose.Pose;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.pose.PoseDetector;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.pose.PoseDetection;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.pose.PoseDetectorOptionsBase;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.pose.PoseLandmark;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.pose.defaults.PoseDetectorOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class PoseDetectionModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

    private static ReactApplicationContext reactContext;

    PoseDetectionModule(ReactApplicationContext context) {
        super(context);
        reactContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "PoseDetection";
    }

  @ReactMethod
  public void findPose(String imagePath, Promise promise) {
    try {
      Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
      InputImage image = InputImage.fromBitmap(bitmap, 0);
      
      PoseDetectorOptions options =
          new PoseDetectorOptions.Builder()
              .setDetectorMode(PoseDetectorOptions.STREAM_MODE)
              .build();

      PoseDetector poseDetector = PoseDetection.getClient(options);
      poseDetector.process(image)
          .addOnSuccessListener(
              pose -> {
                Map<String, Map<String, Float>> landmarks = new HashMap<>();
                pose.getAllPoseLandmarks().forEach(landmark -> {
                  Map<String, Float> position = new HashMap<>();
                  position.put("x", landmark.getPosition().x);
                  position.put("y", landmark.getPosition().y);
                  landmarks.put(landmark.getLandmarkType().name(), position);
                });
                promise.resolve(landmarks);
              })
          .addOnFailureListener(
              e -> promise.reject("Pose detection failed", e));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      promise.reject("Pose detection failed", e);
    }
  }
}

I know a lot of the imports are unused, but that's the result of desperation I guess...
The dependencies in gradle:
dependencies {
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-native:+")
    implementation("com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.3")
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:pose-detection:17.0.1-beta3'
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:pose-detection-accurate:17.0.1-beta3'
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:vision-common:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:vision-interfaces:16.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

I repeat: desperation

Does your Gradle build script pull in all required dependencies? If you think it does, a [mcve] would be helpful.

I edited the post with the dependencies. Is something missing?

Simple answer: the dependencies were not correct.
Apparently you need the latest versions of posedetection.
Currently it's 18.0.0-beta4.
So in the dependencies:
 implementation 'com.google.mlkit:pose-detection:18.0.0-beta4'
 implementation 'com.google.mlkit:pose-detection-accurate:18.0.0-beta4'

